# Changing the Index Name of Data in DBContext with EF Core 7

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm Editing for Compatibility with EF Core 7 and PostgresQL,

```
foreach(var entity in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        foreach(var index in entity.GetIndexes())
        {
            index.Relational().Name = index.Relational().Name.ToSnakeCase();
        }
    }
```

When you search, there are explanations like this, but Relational() is not used on EF Core 7. How can I edit the index name here?

Comment: Are you trying to use Primary Key to change data?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

Comment: You'd need a migration to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SetDatabaseName` extension:

```cs
foreach(var entity in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    foreach(var index in entity.GetIndexes())
    {
        index.SetDatabaseName(index.GetDatabaseName().ToSnakeCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I rearranged the index values with the relevant method